# Make use of a multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
$available_fields = 
Array
(
[316] => test1111
[317] => testsssss1
[318] => 12331
[323] => Array
    (
        [0] => Photo General Inspection small
        [1] => Photo General Inspection medium
        [2] => Photo General Inspection large
    )

)
```

One or some of the values will be arrays.
I want to loop through the array with

```
foreach ($available_fields as $field_id => $label){
            'do something';
        }
```

how can I fix the array in a way that it will not cause an error, and have the $field_id as [323] and $label as Photo General Inspection small.

Comment: Check if $label is itself an array, and if so, access its fist element then instead of working directly with $label.

Comment: You could check if $label is an array and loop through it.

Comment: By "fix" do you mean "if the value is an array, discard everything except the first one"?

Comment: like this? 

if(is_array($label)){
                    foreach($label as $lbl_id => $lbl_value){
                        "do something"
                    }